# how replace string new row mysql

Tags: mysql

As I can create a new record, from a record

example:

```
mysql> select * from user;
+----+--------------+
| id |     name     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |   hola mundo |
+----+--------------+

mysql> select new record;
+----+--------------+
| id |     name     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |   hola       |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |   mundo      |
+----+--------------+
```

i try `remplace(name, ' ', '\r')`;

fuente[1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

fuente[2]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/data-manipulation.html

fuente[3]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

if there is a newer available please enlighten me.

Comment: So your goal is to split strings with whitespace into multiple rows, one word per row in `name`?

Comment: If thats the case pointed by Michael Berkowski then you should do this type of logic at your application level code

Comment: Yes @MichaelBerkowski, failed to realize